# how to react to an intent of the browser?

Tags: android

Yo guys.

You know when u do options/more/share page from the browser? Well I'd like an activity of mine to show up in the menu of all the apps capable of responding to that browser's intent. Thing is I dunno how to write the intent filter in the manifest. Also how do I access data like URL and title of the page which are supposedly add as extra in the intent?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this at the moment to be sure but I think you can register as a SEND intent filter by using the code below and then you should show up as a provider.

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

And then get the text from the extras..

```
Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
String url = callingIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

I would also suggest looking at the [documentation for ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) to see the supported mimetypes and extra key value pairs.

From ACTION_SEND documentation:

> Input: getType() is the MIME type of the data being sent. get*Extra can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in EXTRA_STREAM. Use */* if the MIME type is unknown (this will only allow senders that can handle generic data streams).
>
> Optional standard extras, which may be interpreted by some recipients as appropriate, are: EXTRA_EMAIL, EXTRA_CC, EXTRA_BCC, EXTRA_SUBJECT.